# Email composer with base64 img attachment not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm not a pro programmer but I'm trying to attach a img file using [this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer#attach-base64-encoded-content) plugin in a mobile web app.

Now, the plugin says I have to do something like this to add an attachment

attachments:

```
'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8CAYAAAA6/...'
```

And my base64 img for example is:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJ.......
```

which is saved in the var imgURI

I've tried to do 
attachment: "base64:icon.png//" + $rootScope.imgURI.substring(24),

And also without substring or with substring 25, 26.
In every case the attachment isn'ìt passed to the email composer.
to:, subject:, body:, are working fine.

What am I doing wrong? Can you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use the imageData:

```
var options = {
  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  allowEdit : false,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPG,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions
};

$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

  $scope.fileURI = imageData;

}
```

And, in your cordova EmailComposer code you can do:

```
  var email = {
    app: 'gmail',
    to: YOUR_TO,
    cc: YOUR_CC,
    bcc: YOUR_BCC,
    attachments: [
      $scope.fileURI
    ],
    subject: YOUR_SUBJECT,
    isHtml: true
  };

  $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email).then(null, function () {
    console.log("user cancelled email");
  });
```

It works fine for me, I can see my attached image in my Gmail's mail, for example.